# Are there any design patterns for high performance file parsing?

Tags: java, file, parsing, binary

I've recently developed my own file parsing class called the `BufferedParseStream`, and used this to decode PNG images. I've been comparing it's performance against the open source project [PNGJ](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/), and have seen that for smaller image sizes, PNGJ can be up to twice as fast as my own implementation. I assume this is associated with the implementation overhead when using the `BufferedInputStream`, as PNGJ roll their own [equivalent](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ar.com.hjg/pngj/2.0.1/ar/com/hjg/pngj/BufferedStreamFeeder.java?av=f) instead.

Are there any existing design patterns which guide high performance file parsing, into primitives such as an `int`, `float` etc.?

```
public class BufferedParseStream extends BufferedInputStream {

private final ByteBuffer  mByteBuffer;

public BufferedParseStream(final InputStream pInputStream, final int pBufferSize) {
    super(pInputStream, pBufferSize);
    /* Initialize the ByteBuffer. */
    this.mByteBuffer  = DataUtils.delegateNative(new byte[8]);
}

private final void buffer(final int pNumBytes) throws IOException {
    /* Read the bytes into the ByteStorage. */
    this.read(this.getByteBuffer().array(), 0, pNumBytes);
    /* Reset the ByteBuffer Location. */
    this.getByteBuffer().position(0);
}

public final char parseChar() throws IOException {
    /* Read a single byte. */
    this.buffer(DataUtils.BYTES_PER_CHAR);
    /* Return the corresponding character. */
    return this.getByteBuffer().getChar();
}

public final int parseInt() throws IOException {
    /* Read four bytes. */
    this.buffer(DataUtils.BYTES_PER_INT);
    /* Return the corresponding integer. */
    return this.getByteBuffer().getInt();
}

public final long parseLong() throws IOException {
    /* Read eight bytes. */
    this.buffer(DataUtils.BYTES_PER_LONG);
    /* Return the corresponding long. */
    return this.getByteBuffer().getLong();
}

public final void setParseOrder(final ByteOrder pByteOrder) {
    this.getByteBuffer().order(pByteOrder);
}

private final ByteBuffer getByteBuffer() {
    return this.mByteBuffer;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think we can talk about design patterns in such cases, it would rather be algorithm optimizations, which are most of the time algorithm-specific. Try to identify which part of your code takes too much time and fix it

Comment: I understand, sorry for confusing the terminology. Do you see anything particularly flawed about the `BufferedParseStream`?

Comment: Not particularly but I don't know much about this classes and methods. Is this the only part of code you wrote ? Isn't there a class that decodes a PNG image ? If you wrote it, this is te part that is most likely unefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java nio should be faster than using input streams, your class that you present seems odd to me (might just be me though :)) because it has an extra layer on top of ByteBuffer which I don't think is required.

You should use the byte buffer directly, it has a getInt, getFloat method which you can feed directly in to the required variables.

I think though your performance problems  could be in the PNG decoder code as someone else has already mentioned. You should post that for further analysis

Comment: I didn't realise that I was adding that extra layer of complexity! I'll refactor my work to eliminate that redundant component.

In terms of the PNG Decoder in general, I brought up this problem because other the method of streaming I had adopted, the external code was roughly identical. This is due to the limited choice in algorithms you can use when parsing pixels, and streaming these into a buffer. Thanks for your advice.

(Also welcome to SO!)